# Ribbon TooltipOpened

Tags: wpf, ribbon

I try to get a EventTrigger from a Event ToolTipOpening on a RibbonSplitButton
but I never get any event, no problems with other Events.

```
<RibbonSplitButton Label="Move File Down" Command="{BindingMoveFileDownCommandDetermine}" SmallImageSource="Images/32/MoveDown.ico" ToolTipTitle="Move File Down" ToolTipDescription="{Binding TextForMoveDown}" ToolTipOpening="RibbonSplitButton_ToolTipOpening" >       
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="ToolTipOpening">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MoveFileDownCommandDetermine}"/>                            
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

...
Thanks for Help

Answer (score 1):

The `ToolTipOpening` event is inherited from `FrameworkElement` and the event is not being raised for a RibbonSplitButton.

If you set the inherited `Tooltip` property you will notice that this tooltip won't actually show up.

Instead of handling the `ToolTipOpening` event you could handle the `MouseEnter` event:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MoveFileDownCommandDetermine}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```